# string.Replace is not replacing double backslashes from my string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, replace, settings

I need to run some kind of application by clicking on a button on my form, 
I'am talking about WPF desktop application, and about C# as a programming language, and today I faced an issue, I tried to run some kind of application on my button key down but I realized with my debugger that my path is writen like this: (I'm keepin path in my Settings.setting file and there I did not use double backslashes and that is my first quuestion, why is my path looking like that, **mentioned below**.)

**C:\\MyComputer\\MyApplication\\Application.exe**

and I need it written with single backslashes, what I tried to do is posted below:

```
 private void OpenApplication_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
            string path = Globals.MyApplicationPath;
            string path2 = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
            //path2 is still dobule backshashed :(

            if (Directory.Exists(path2))
            {
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.FileName = Globals.MyApplicationPath;
                Process.Start(start);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Path is not correct.");
            }
 }
```

I realized `Directory.Exists(path2)` is allways false, so it acctually means that my path does not exist, even if it exist, so I guess I need to remove "\\" and replace it with "\" :)

Comment: `why is my path looking like that` it is what you see in debugger window. use the *magnifier* icon to see the content as text. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379763/932418

Comment: @L.B using magnifier icon my value looks fine, but it's allways false even if that path exists 100% .. :/

Comment: If the path exists without slashes in the settings, then it will not have slashes in code. You are simply looking at the way C# handles that character. The path does NOT exist. You think it does. That is your problem. Take another hard look. Grab the string using the magnifier icon as suggested and paste it in Explorer directly, see if it opens the folder.

Comment: @Juan that's how I tested it, grabbed value shown with magnifier icon and pasted it in a explorer, and application runned, while Directory.Exist says that my path does not exist :)

Comment: Please post a snapshot of the debugger screen and snapshot of the folder in Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

Your path contains a file name. The `Directory.Exists()` method will return false because that is not a valid **directory** name.

If what you are looking to do is find the directory, then strip the file name and then check:

```
var path2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var exists = Directory.Exists(path2) //This should be true
```

If what you want is to find out if the file exists, use:

```
File.Exists(path)
```

So your code becomes:

```
private void OpenApplication_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        if (File.Exists(Globals.MyApplicationPath))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = Globals.MyApplicationPath;
            Process.Start(start);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Path is not correct.");
        }
}
```

Comment: looks like this is true, but than how could I run an application for example Word.exe if I extract Word.exe from a path name, but yes this what you said was true, but unfortunatelly did not fix my issue at all, but vote up!

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: That should have been enough to point you in the right direction. Anyways, I updated my answer with what you need. Take another read.